# Accessing property in union of object types fails for properties not defined on all union members

Tags: typescript, union-types

I am facing a scenario where a HTTP call's response varies according to region.
I have specify return type of the object. So if I declare suppose 4 types and use union of these as a wrapper type.

Problem arises as there are fields which are not common to everything.
Is the solution to this is to make those fields or optional.
For me making a field optional means it is not necessary which is not true in this case . As this to make the Tslint error go Away.

Please tell me if you are failing to understand my question

EDIT:-

```
function mapAddress(address: AddressRegionXX | AddressRegionYY,region:string): AddressWithIdXX | AddressWithIdXX   {
  let addressId = address.id ? address.id : "XX";

  let addressType = addressId == "XX" ? "subbed" : "unsubbed";
 if(region == "XX"){
  return {
    firstName: address.first_name || null,
    lastName: address.last_name || null,
    street1: address.addr_1 || null,
    street2: address.addr_2 || null,
    city: address.city || null,
    state: address.state || null,
    postalCode: address.zip_code || null,
    phone: address.phone_number || null,
    addressId: addressId,
    addressType: addressType
  };
   if(region == "XX"){
  return {
    fName: address.f_name || null,
    lName: address.l_name || null,
    address: address.addr_1 || null,
    roomNo: address.addr_2 || null,
    district: address.district|| null,
    state: address.state || null,
    pinCode: address.zip_code || null,
    phoneNumber: address.phone_number || null,
    addressId: addressId,
    addressType: addressType
  };
 }
}
```

This is the context of where I have to use Union type
Here the response depending on each region address type would change there is long list which is not practical to include here.
As I have shown here field names varies for each region and for some additional fields are there .
So what is the elegant way to tackle this situation is it proper to use conditional types . Is there any alternative to union type.
As in the ened there would be atleast 5-6  address type and chance for more in future.

```
In layman terms 
is there any miraculous way in which :D 
We write something Like
type correctTypeAddress<T> =
    T extends Address? AddressXX :
    T extends Address? AddressYY :
```

mapAddress(address: AddressRegion,region:string):correctTypeAddress

Below is an example of what I am dealing with all types does not have same properties. So How to deal with non uniform type mappings 
Is there any alternative to using union type when

**Way of recreating the problem**

```
type typeA = {
  prop1:string;
  prop2:string;
}

type typeB = {
  prop1: string;
  prop3: string;
}
type typeC = {
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
}
type mappedType = typeA | typeB | typeC;

const a = (b): mappedType => {

  return {
    prop1:"1",
    prop5:"3"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:-** Applying conditional types but using generic leads to another lint error as `Property 'prop1' does not exist on type 'T'`

```
type typeIA = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

type typeIB = {
  prop1: string;
  prop3: string;
}
type typeIC = {
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
}

type typeOA = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

type typeOB = {
  prop1: string;
  prop3: string;
}
type typeOC = {
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
}
// type mappedType = typeA | typeB | typeC;

const a = <T extends typeIA | typeIB | typeIC>(_b: T): T extends typeIA ? typeOA : never | T extends typeIB ? typeOB : never | T extends typeIC ? typeOC : never=> {
  if (_b.prop1 == "1"){
   return {
     prop1: "1",
     prop3: "3"
   } as T extends typeIA ? typeOA : never | T extends typeIB ? typeOB : never | T extends typeIC ? typeOC : never
 }else{
    return {
      prop1: "1",
      prop2: "2"
    } as T extends typeIA ? typeOA : never | T extends typeIB ? typeOB : never | T extends typeIC ? typeOC : never
 }

}
const c = a({prop1:"1",prop2:"2"});

const d = a({ prop1: "1", prop3: "2" });

const e = a({ prop4: "1", prop5: "2" });
```

Comment: just use [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types)?

Comment: Please edit this question to provide a [mcve] of your issue so that someone can make a suggestion which directly addresses it.   Otherwise any answer will just be a guess about the actual problem you're facing.

Comment: @jcalz can you please take a look now

Comment: I would love to look at this but the barrier to entry is still too high.  In order to get that code even to compile without errors to start working on an answer, someone will need to invent interface/type definitions for types like `AddressRegion`, etc.  Could you do that?  Ideally you will give us some code that someone can drop as-is into an IDE (like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//)) and start to make modifications and suggestions.  The only errors should be those relevant to the issue.  That's the "complete" and "verifiable" parts of an [mcve].   Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz more than fixing that particular error what I was looking for was a way of using conditional types to overcome the use of union type if that makes sense

Comment: Ideally the Q and A would look like this: "Q: Here is some code which is tedious and doesn't scale.  Is there some better way to do it?  A: Here is some changed code which *has the same effect* but is less tedious and scales better."  I'm asking you to do the Q part.  If your example code is full of errors then either I have to fix them myself or I have to accept errors in the answer code, which means I can't test the answer, which means maybe it won't work.  I personally  don't feel comfortable suggesting an answer that I can't test.  Maybe someone else will come along who feels differently.

Comment: @jcalz I understand where you are coming from. I would try to make it conform to your standards :D

Comment: linter will throw error in VScode when you return something that does not have all properties in all types .Hope you understand the context

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see a [mcve] anywhere.  You've got text formatted as code, code formatted as text, and the only code that doesn't error is that union at the end, and you're not using it to do anything.  I'd suggest you carefully review the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  I wish you good luck in getting an answer, and I'm sorry I can't be of further assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full explanation of why this is the 'best' way (i joke there is no best way) probably is outside the scope of a stack overflow answer but essentially a quick few points would be:

1. to get keyof union typesaftely you need to turn it into an
   intersection keyof (A | B) to keyof (A & B)
2. Using 'Maybe' in which you can have two possible outcomes doubles as a solution for undefined/null, however in this case it solves that when picking from a union you could have 'Something' which will be typeA or typeB or nothing which is case typeC
3. Conditional ReturnTypes are generally worse than overloading simply because the second you have a conditional return type you pretty much are sentencing yourself to have to cast in some way the return value.
4. Read more about Scala's 'Option' or Haskells 'Maybe' of which this solution is based off somewhere else, is it's outside the scope of this answer but this solution basically stole its best ideas.

Long code snippet incoming. Hope this helps this will feel excessive but it isn't.

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = [U] extends [never]
    ? never
    : (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void)
        ? I
        : never;
export type UnionMembersWith<T, K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<T>> = [T] extends [never]
    ? never
    : Exclude<T, Exclude<T, Partial<Record<K, any>>>>;

export type Maybe<A> = _None<A> | _Some<A>;

type PickReturn<A, K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<A>> = [K] extends [never]
    ? typeof None
    : [K] extends [keyof UnionMembersWith<A, K>]
        ? Maybe<NonNullable<UnionMembersWith<A, K>[K]>>
        : [K] extends [keyof A]
            ? Maybe<NonNullable<A[K]>>
            : typeof None


class _Some<A> {
    readonly _tag: "some" = "some";
    readonly value: A;
    constructor(value: A) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    map<U>(f: (a: A) => U): Maybe<U> {
      return new _Some(f(this.value));
    }

    flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Maybe<B>): Maybe<B> {
      return f(this.value);
    }

    pick<K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<A>>(key: K): PickReturn<A, K> {
      return Maybe((this.value as any)[key]) as any;
    }

    get get(): A | undefined {
        return this.value;
    }
}

class _None<A = never> {
    static value: Maybe<never> = new _None();
    readonly _tag = "none";

    map<U>(f: (a: A) => U): Maybe<U> {
        return this as any;
    }

    flatMap<B>(f: (a: A) => Maybe<B>): Maybe<B> {
        return this as any;
    }

    pick<K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<A>>(key: K): PickReturn<A, K> {
        return this as any;
    }

    get get(): A | undefined {
        return undefined;
    }

    getOrElse(none: never[]): [A] extends [Array<any>] ? A : A | never[];
    getOrElse<B>(none: B): A | B;
    getOrElse<B>(none: B): A | B {
        return none as any;
    }
}

export const None: Maybe<never> = _None.value;
export const Some = <A>(a: A): _Some<A> => new _Some(a);

export function Maybe<A>(value: A | null | undefined): Maybe<A> {
    if (value !== null && value !== undefined) return Some(value);
    return None;
}

//* END IMPLEMNTATION */


type typeIA = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

type typeIB = {
  prop1: string;
  prop3: string;
}
type typeIC = {
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
}

type typeOA = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
}

type typeOB = {
  prop1: string;
  prop3: string;
}
type typeOC = {
  prop4: string;
  prop5: string;
}
// type mappedType = typeA | typeB | typeC;

function a(_b: typeIC): typeOC
function a(_b: typeIB): typeOB
function a(_b: typeIA): typeOA
function a(_b: typeIA | typeIB | typeIC): typeOA | typeOB | typeOC {
    /* 100% typesafe */
  if (Maybe(_b).pick("prop1").get === "1"){
   return {
     prop1: "1",
     prop3: "3"
   }
 }else{
    return {
      prop1: "1",
      prop2: "2"
    }
 }

}

const c = a({prop1:"1",prop2:"2"}); // type oA
const d = a({ prop1: "1", prop3: "2" }); // type oB
const e = a({ prop4: "1", prop5: "2" }); // type oC
```

EDIT: "The Know More":
Maybe isn't meant to be a solution to this one off problem for you but a solution to a certain type of 'effect' that can occur in programming. Maybe is monadic and monads trap effects, the effect Maybe traps is non-determinism and the idea here is that Maybe abstracts it away so you don't have to think about it.

The point here can be easily missed because any other overflow'er will claim that this can easily be solved by nesting 'If/Else''s but the idea of Maybe is that it's an abstraction in which you no longer need to check if things ARE or AREN"T there and therefore no longer need If/Else

so that's alot of words what does that look like? So this code is both runtime and type-level safe.

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    children: IPerson[] | undefined;
}

const person = {
    name: "Sally",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Billy",
            children: [
                {
                    name: "Suzie",
                    children: undefined
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};

const test = Maybe(person).pick("children").pick(0).pick("children").pick(0).get;  // Typesafe / Runtime safe possible path
const test = Maybe(person).pick("children").pick(0).pick("children").pick(10000).get ; // Typesafe / Runtime safe impossible paths

/* We have 'Children' which is non-deterministic it could be undefined OR it could be defined */
/* Let's wrap person in Maybe so we don't care whther its there or not there anymore */
const test2 = Maybe(person).pick("children").map((childrenArr) => {
    return childrenArr.map((child) => child.name.toUpperCase())
}).getOrElse([]);  // string[] notice how when using things in the context of our Maybe we cease to care about undefined.


const test3 = Maybe(person).pick("children").pick(10000).map((person) => {
    return {...person, name: person.name.toUpperCase()} // safe even though there's no person at Array index 10000
}).getOrElse({name: "John Doe", children: []})   // IPerson even though there is no person at Array index 10000
```

Comment: Shanon I am very much intrigued by your answer but honestly I am out of depth here. I am trying to wrap my head around your answer. It would be awesome if you can wrap add coments to explain the same. If its not too much to ask

Comment: It's very hard to explain but iv'e done my best, the basic answer is that Maybe allows you to never have to use if/else or even nested if/else when doing things that are non-determinisitc such as accessing union members properties when they dont all have that property, and such as using values that can be null | undefined

Comment: Yeah got that part already . I was thinking of building a maybe myself. So I could understand it myself. I was thinking along the same lines of using intersection that would mean all properties be accessible .But in reality that would be not right as it should be either TypeIA or TypeIB or TypeIC . But with maybe it would great solution to the conundrum

Answer (score 1):

I see following options (you may combine them):

1. Function overloading

   ```
   interface AddressRegionXX {
       id: string;
       first_name?: string;
       last_name?: string;
   }  

   interface AddressRegionYY {
       f_name?: string;
       l_name?: string;
   }

   interface AddressWithIdXX {
       firstName: string | null;
       lastName: string | null;
       addressId: string;
       addressType: string;
   }

   interface AddressWithIdYY {
       fName: string | null;
       lName: string | null;
       addressId: string;
       addressType: string;
   }

   function mapAddress(address: AddressRegionXX, region: string): AddressWithIdXX;
   function mapAddress(address: AddressRegionYY, region: string): AddressWithIdYY;
   function mapAddress(address: AddressRegionXX | AddressRegionYY, region: string): AddressWithIdXX | AddressWithIdYY {
       let addressId = (<AddressRegionXX>address).id ? (<AddressRegionXX>address).id : "XX";

       let addressType = addressId == "XX" ? "subbed" : "unsubbed";
       if (region == "XX") {
           let AddressRegion = <AddressRegionXX>address;
           return {
               firstName: AddressRegion.first_name || null,
               lastName: AddressRegion.last_name || null,
               addressId: addressId,
               addressType: addressType
           };
       }
       if (region == "YY") {
           let AddressRegion = <AddressRegionYY>address;
           return {
               fName: AddressRegion.f_name || null,
               lName: AddressRegion.l_name || null,
               addressId: addressId,
               addressType: addressType
           };
       }
   }

   // Usage
   let aXX: AddressRegionXX = { id: "idXX" };
   let resXX: AddressWithIdXX = mapAddress(aXX, "XX");

   let aYY: AddressRegionYY = { };
   let resYY: AddressWithIdYY = mapAddress(aYY, "YY");
   ```

   Good point here is to have result of exact type depending of agrument type. For `address` of type `AddressRegionXX` you'll get result of type `AddressWithIdXX`.

   Problem with this approach is that you should be very carefull when implementing `mapAddress` function. Code inside it has no knowledge about type of `address`, so you should relay on some additional conditions. (Typescript code will be transpiled to JavaScript and all interfaces will be removed).
2. Use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

   ```
   enum TypeDiscriminant {
       addressXX,
       addressYY
   }

   interface AddressRegionXX {
       TypeDiscriminant: TypeDiscriminant.addressXX;
       id: string;
       first_name?: string;
       last_name?: string;
   }

   interface AddressRegionYY {
       TypeDiscriminant: TypeDiscriminant.addressYY;
       f_name?: string;
       l_name?: string;
   }

   interface AddressWithIdXX {
       firstName: string | null;
       lastName: string | null;
       addressId: string;
       addressType: string;
   }

   interface AddressWithIdYY {
       fName: string | null;
       lName: string | null;
       addressId: string;
       addressType: string;
   }

   function mapAddress3(address: AddressRegionXX | AddressRegionYY, region: string): AddressWithIdXX | AddressWithIdYY {
       let addressId = (<AddressRegionXX>address).id ? (<AddressRegionXX>address).id : "XX";

       let addressType = addressId == "XX" ? "subbed" : "unsubbed";
       switch (address.TypeDiscriminant) {
           case TypeDiscriminant.addressXX:
               return {
                   firstName: address.first_name || null,
                   lastName: address.last_name || null,
                   addressId: addressId,
                   addressType: addressType
               };
           case TypeDiscriminant.addressYY:
               return {
                   fName: address.f_name || null,
                   lName: address.l_name || null,
                   addressId: addressId,
                   addressType: addressType
               };
       }
   }
   // Usage
   let AXX: AddressRegionXX = { id: "idXX", TypeDiscriminant: TypeDiscriminant.addressXX };
   let resAXX = mapAddress3(AXX, "XX");

   let AYY: AddressRegionYY = { TypeDiscriminant: TypeDiscriminant.addressYY };
   let resAYY = mapAddress3(AYY, "YY");
   ```

   Good point here is that `mapAddress3` now know exact type of `address`.

   Problem is that `resAXX` and `resAYY` will have type of `AddressWithIdXX | AddressWithIdYY`. Typescript cannot know what type will be returned untill `mapAddress3` will be executed.
3. Third option can use conditional types to return correct type like this

   ```
   function mapAddress4<T extends AddressRegionXX | AddressRegionYY>(address: T, region: string): T extends AddressRegionXX ? AddressWithIdXX : AddressWithIdYY;
   ```

   And expected usage will be

   ```
   var a4XX: AddressRegionXX = { id: "idAA" };
   var resa4XX: AddressWithIdXX = mapAddress4(a4XX, "XX");
   ```

   But this is not possible. See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929)

Comment: I have tried out option3  but that causes another problem. But what I was trying to figure was a solution along the lines option 3 I was reading into conditional types

Comment: I have updated the question with your answer and its error

Comment: Option 3 is not possible. Please see here https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929